# How to centre a WPF path in a panel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to draw a shape on the bottom section of a user control. The idea is that the shape will be made visible or collapsed from within code and the overall control will expand or contract according to whether or not the shape is visible. Here's what I have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GsnEd2.View.GoalControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GsnEd2.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="130" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DockPanel Name="MainView">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="DecoratorCanvas">
                <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stroke="Black" Fill="Ivory" Data="M 0, 0 l 10, 10 l -10, 10 l -10, -10 l 10, -10"/>

            </Grid>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Ivory">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Label Content="Id" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0, 1, 0, 0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label Content="Module Id"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="Goal"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="BlueViolet" BorderThickness="1" Name="SelectedBorder" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The trouble is, it's not centred horizontally; it's offset a bit to the left. I think the problem is that those negative values don't count towards the shape's size, but what do I do about it?

(Also, I want to be able to change the size of the shape - all those 10s - from within the program, but the XAML seems to insist on just numbers and letters in the path definition string - should I make that another question?)

Comment: Give the path a height and width and set stretch to fill.

Comment: And for the "numbers and letters": the type of the Data property is `Geometry`. Take a look at the online documentation.

Comment: I would also suggest you take dockpanel off your list off preferred panels. It is rarely useful imo

Comment: Usually it's best to go with a grid which has columns and rows as your main layout container.

Comment: I find DockPanel ideal for laying out a classic menu bat + ribbon at the top. status bar at the bottom, toolbar at the left, and content in the rest. But I agree it doesn't work here.

Comment: Ok, giving the path a height and width and stretching to fill  is wrong by the stroke width, but users will never notice that so it will do. It means I have to calculate the width as 2 * the distance I'm moving each time - presumably I need a converter to do the multiplication? And best to give the scale as a parameter?

Because that was a comment, I can't give you credit for the solution...

Comment: The Geometry doesn't seem to help. I get as far as <LineSegment Point="20, 10"/>, but I can't bind to the values inside the string and I can't enclose the point in the LineSegment:
    <LineSegment>
        <Point X="20" Y="0"/>
     </LineSegment>
is an error.